# Ways to increase texture resolution

Tags: texturing

I have a quite big object to texturize and even with 4k resolution textures are blurry. Ofcourse I will overlap everything that I can, but it's still not enough. The model is hull for transport and I see only one variant - to split it on outside part and inside part (so it will be easier to use substance smart materials).

But how can I do this so it will be correct way? I mean if for example my model will be imported in some game engine. Should I do it it like that:
[image]

Or using one sided models even if they be inside each other a bad idea and I should do something like that:
[image]

In second case area is still big but I can just overlap and squize to minimum invisible parts that will be inside each over.

Or maybe there's more ways to resolve my problem? I'm not very experiensed unfortunatelly :(

I know that there's UDIM variant but I think it's not correct to use them in my situation.